# How to export full stash list from one laptop to other

Tags: git, github, git-stash

I am using git version 2.32.0
I just want to export the full stash list saved in my old laptop to new laptop.
How can I do so?

Comment: a word of advice : don't use the stash as a place to store long term things. If you need some of these commits, name them (with branches or tags or custom refs ... e.g : `my/workspace/xyz`)

Comment: I'm a heavy user of `git stash`, and all too often I find myself searching waaay to long where I left that piece of code I had written.

Comment: @LeGEC: yeah, `git stash` is like nicotine or other bad habits, hard to stop even though it keeps killing you :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can export each stash to a patch file with `git stash show -p` and apply it on the other machine. But the best way is: Don't even try. Zip up the *whole* working tree on the old laptop and move it to the new laptop and use it there. Actually what I do is `rsync` between machines.

Comment: I was searching some clever trick within git, but I'm afraid you're right, @matt. Nor `git bundle` nor some `xargs`ing on `git stash list` seem to be satisfactory, let alone practical.

Comment: Copying over the repository from `old` to `new` has the added benefit of preserving all the reflogs (not just the stash). If the OP wants to start from a "fresh worktree", he can just copy the `.git/` directory and run `git checkout .` to get a fresh checkout of the latest commit he was working on.

Comment: @RomainValeri : I was looking into impractical ;) ways to transfer commits from `old` to `new`, piping the output of `git stash list --format="%H"` into `xargs git fetch user@old:path/to/repo` (or `xargs git fetch ../copy_from_old_repo`) works well enough. Once done you just have to copy the `.git/logs/refs/stash` (and perhaps `.git/refs/stash`) files to complete the "transfer".